# How to save array of tuples in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I am using a tuple of arrays in one of my files and want to start saving it in `UserDefaults`. Here is how I am storing my current data:

```
typealias savemytuple = (Name: String, NameID: String, BookID: String, Picture: NSData)
var savefun = [savemytuple]()
```

I have researched and found I may need to do something with the following for saving:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject
```

And this for retrieving:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData
```

Not sure if this way will work as my tuple has multiple data types. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You should take a look at the Codable protocol (Swift 4 / Xcode 9.x). Don't use UserDefaults to persist your App data. Use a struct instead of a tuple and just write your resulting JSON data array to your application support folder.

Answer (score 16):

The values in `UserDefaults` must be [property lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356066/77567), so you need to convert each tuple to a property list. A `Data` is a property list, and there are several ways to convert things to `Data`.

One way is to stop using a tuple and use a `struct` instead. If all of the `struct`'s stored properties conform to `Codable`, then you can ask Swift to generate everything needed to make the `struct` itself conform to `Codable` just by declaring the conformance. Both `String` and `Data` conform to `Codable`.

Once the `struct` is `Codable`, you can convert one of them, or even an array of them, into a property list via `JSONEncoder` or `PropertyListEncoder`:

```
import Foundation

struct Bookie: Codable {
    var name: String
    var nameId: String
    var bookId: String
    var picture: Data
}

let bookies = [
    Bookie(name: "mbro12", nameId: "id1", bookId: "b1", picture: Data()),
    Bookie(name: "mayoff", nameId: "id2", bookId: "b2", picture: Data())
]
let bookiesData = try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(bookies)
UserDefaults.standard.set(bookiesData, forKey: "bookies")

let fetchedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "bookies")!
let fetchedBookies = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Bookie].self, from: fetchedData)
print(fetchedBookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the tuples into Dictionary to save it, not really a proper way, rather make your tuple into a custom object, then conform `NSCoding` protocol for a proper way to convert between data and object.

You don't really need `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject`, just simply convert the tuple into a Dictionary and have another function to convert back to the tuple type.